# Extracts text from tags

Tags: php

I have an HTML in string, I am trying to extract it and put into variable.

**HTML**

```
<b>App name</b>
v1.1.5 by
<a href="#">Link</a>
<br>
some description of app -
<a href="#">options</a>
<br>
<small style="color:#666">By Android market</small>
```

---

My main problem is that some text are not warped by HTML tag, like `v1.1.5 by` and `some description of app`.

**How do I get all text inside and out side tags and put them in array ? I have not tried any code cuz I dont know get the text of not warped by tag**

Comment: Use a regular expression. But the question is.. what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) + [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) + [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
<?php
// header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$str = <<<HTM
<b>App name</b>
v1.1.5 by
<a href="#">Link</a>
<br>
some description of app -
<a href="#">options</a>
<br>
<small style="color:#666">By Android market</small>
HTM;

$buffer = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, strip_tags($str)));

var_dump($buffer);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "App name"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "v1.1.5 by"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Link"
  [4]=>
  string(25) "some description of app -"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "options"
  [7]=>
  string(17) "By Android market"
}
```

Comment: Do I must need to use header ?

Comment: @user007 no. It is just for debugging purposes. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, and if my html is inside a VAR then can I do like this ? `$str = <<<HTM $html HTM;`

Comment: @user007 , just try this: `$buffer = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, strip_tags($YOUR_VAR_HERE)));`

Comment: it just return one array, not like your OUTPUT

Comment: @user007 play with it. There are dozen of ways to perform that. Unfotunately, I can not see your code, do determine the problem.

Comment: the problem is due to there is not any line brek, I will add it